# Thread.sleep in junit test also invoke InterruptedException

Tags: java, maven, junit4

My Junit version is 4.12

```
@Test
public void test()throws InterruptException{
   doSomething();
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   AssertResult();
}
```

When I run `mvn test`. I got a InterruptException.But when i run with ItelliJ Idea, this case will pass. 
Even if I add timeout to my test case like this,I still got a InterruptException.

```
@Test(timeout=10000)
public void test()throws InterruptException{
    doSomething();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    AssertResult();
}
```

Then i add a method realSleep to process it.Then case passed.But I think it not a graceful solution.

```
public static void realSleep(long time){
   long start = System.currentTimeMills();
   while(true){
       try{
           Thread.sleep(time)
       }catch(InterruptedException e){
       }
       if(System.currentTimeMills()-start>time){
           return
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.It's my spelling mistakes.I corrected it.

Comment: Check out [this](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2925). And I'd add the [maven] tag.

Comment: Thank you.I will try to fix it.

Comment: Besides, What the InterruptedException is invoked remain a question.

Comment: I can't tell you why that is. The JVM for example can interrupt waiting threads for performance reasons but I don't know if this also can happen with sleeping threads. Most likely the problem has to do with maven. Just chill out and maybe some maven expert can tell you what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @JainPing, Did you manage to solve this? Thanks